# PHP Regex: Remove words less than 3 characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove all words of less than 3 characters from a string, specifically with RegEx.

The following doesn't work because it is looking for double spaces. I suppose I could convert all spaces to double spaces beforehand and then convert them back after, but that doesn't seem very efficient. Any ideas?

```
$text='an of and then some an ee halved or or whenever';
$text=preg_replace('@ [a-z]{1,2} @',' ',' '.$text.' ');
echo trim($text);
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the word boundary tag: `\b`:

Replace: `\b[a-z]{1,2}\b` with `''`

Answer (score 10):

**Removing the Short Words**

You can use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~\b[a-z]{1,2}\b\~', '', $yourstring);
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/yP0hI0), see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- `\b` is a word boundary that matches a position where one side is a letter, and the other side is not a letter (for instance a space character, or the beginning of the string)
- `[a-z]{1,2}` matches one or two letters
- `\b` another word boundary
- Replace with the empty string.

**Option 2: Also Remove Trailing Spaces**

If you also want to remove the spaces after the words, we can add `\s*` at the end of the regex:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~\b[a-z]{1,2}\b\s*~', '', $yourstring);
```

**Reference**

[Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Thank you but I don't want any of this unnecessary complexity, especially the case-insensitivity.

Comment: Okay, took it out. Now it's simple as possible. Also edited the explanation, and will add a demo in 20 seconds. :)

Comment: Made the removal of the trailing spaces an Option 2 at the bottom, that way you have the simplest at the top, and an additional option at the bottom.

Comment: +1 from me - but what if we need to remove all words NOT EQUAL 3 chars ? for example from your demo only word 'and' should be left in substitution...thx for a hint

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
preg_replace('/(\b.{1,2}\s)/','',$your_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

As some solutions worked here, they had a problem with my language's "multichar characters", such as "ch". A simple explode and implode worked for me.

```
$maxWordLength = 3;
$string = "my super string";
$exploded = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($exploded as $key => $word) {
    if(mb_strlen($word) < $maxWordLength) unset($exploded[$key]);
}
$string = implode(" ", $exploded);
echo $string;

// outputs "super string"
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems that this hack works fine with most PHP versions:

```
$string2 = preg_replace("/~\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}\b\~/i", "", trim($string1));
```

Where `[a-zA-Z0-9]` are the accepted Char/Number range.

Comment: Hey Pietro, welcome to SO. It looks like this is very similar to an existing answer and only adds your commentary to it. Please refrain from posting answers as a comment. I do see you don't have yet enough reputation to comment, but perhaps with different contributions you'll be able soon (e.g. providing an actual answer to another question already contributed). Don't be afraid thought, your answer might get downvoted and deleted, as this is the common way content on the site is managed by the community (voting). Have a good start and please don't feel interrupted too much on your path!